# How to skip an element when using every

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an object:

```
obj = {name:null, lastName:null, scores:[]}
```

I need to iterate and check whether all fields are null , except for the scores field. I need to skip that.

I was using

```
  Object.values(obj).every(x=> x===null)
```

before the scores was added, but I'm not sure how to skip that field now. Because regardless if the scores array is empty or not, if all other fields are null I need to return true.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your code... shouldn't it be `obj[x] === null`?

Comment: Object.keys(obj).every(x=>  x==='scores' || x===null)

Comment: What's your end goal? Are you trying to filter out the null values?

Comment: @AZ_ that doesn't work, you're comparing `x` (the key) to `null`, not the value.

Comment: yea @Alnitak already noticed, but cannot update. must be obj[x],
I just cared about skipping the score as asked in question and didnt check the rest code.

Comment: @Alnitak and also noticed checking the null values before 'score' is better.

Comment: I was using Object.values, I apologize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use ES7 (and shims are available if you can't) you can use this which avoids iterating over the object twice:

```
Object.entries(obj).every(([k, v]) => v === null || k === 'scores');
```

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) works in every current mainstream browser except MSIE.

The other advantage of `Object.entries` is that since the callback is passed both the key and the value, there's no need to access `obj` within the callback, which in turn forces the use of an inline function forming a closure over `obj`.   With `.entries()` it's completely possible to make the callback a separate function, which would be especially important if the code were to get much longer, or if that callback logic was required in multiple places.

Answer (score 6):

You could `filter` the keys you do not want to check:

```
Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(k => k !== "scores")
    .every(k => obj[k] === null);
```

<sup>*It is possible to combine the two conditions inside every (just return true for keys you do not want to check) but I chose to keep the logic separate.*</sup>

Comment: although it's ES7, I prefer `Object.entries` because it gives access to both the key and value within the callback without having to form a closure over `obj` (thereby also allowing use of a non-inline function)